# Read csv file but with tab delimiter

Tags: weka

I am using this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/News+Aggregator

The dataset, although `.csv` file, but it uses tab to separate columns instead of `,`. When I try to read it using Weka (latest version), it throws me the error.

I tried converting to other format (using other delimiters) but it does not work and still throws the same error. How should I read this file?

Comment: "_I tried converting to other format but it does not work._" This is not a problem description. _What_ did you try, and _how_ did it not work?

Comment: I converted it to other delims, but it still throws me the error.

Comment: _What_ error? you have never quoted one.